# yum not able to install a package

Tags: centos, yum

```
[root@mypc yum.repos.d]# yum search perl-Locale-gettext
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, fastestmirror
Repository tmz-puppet is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * epel: mirrors.tummy.com
 * extras: eq-centosrepo.hopto.org
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirror.team-cymru.org
=================================================================== N/S Matched: perl-Locale-gettext ====================================================================
perl-Locale-gettext.x86_64 : Internationalization for Perl

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
[root@mypc yum.repos.d]
```

And

```
[root@mypc yum.repos.d]# yum install perl-Locale-gettext
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, fastestmirror
Repository tmz-puppet is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: mir01.syntis.net
 * base: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * epel: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.lstn.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.choopa.net
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do
[root@mypc yum.repos.d]#
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you post what is in your `/etc/yum.repo.d/`?

Comment: @jokerdino That contains lots of custom repos. But, the package I'm trying to install is in rpmforge.

Comment: (1) You might want to first resolve "Repository tmz-puppet is listed more than once in the configuration". (2) does `yum`'s `-v` option print anything enlightening?

Comment: Nothing that would help. `http://sprunge.us/ZOPM`

Comment: That message is giving when the package is already installed (among other conditions).  Check and see if it is already there....

Answer (score 0):

The output in your question is consistent with the package being already installed. What do you get from the following commands?

```
# yum list | grep -i perl-Locale-gettext
perl-Locale-gettext.x86_64               1.05-1.el6.rf                 rpmforge
# rpm -qa | grep -i perl-Locale-gettext
#
```

Are you doing this from within the Dell.com IT environment?

Comment: I finally got the reason why this was happening. See my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was that the package `perl-Locale-gettext` was obsoleted by `perl-gettext` & I had `perl-gettext` already installed. We shifted some infrastructure to Centos6 and the old boxes had `Locale` package installed. And as we used `puppet` to manage the boxes, it was throwing the `cannot install package` error.

But, `yum` was not kind enough to say that. I only got to know about that after I tried installing the package by doing `rpm -ivh /path/to/package`.